# Excel Match Index multiple criteria and multiple dates

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, formula

[image]

```
=INDEX(D1:D6;MATCH(1;(E1=A1:A6)*(E2=B2:B6)*(DATEVALUE(MID(E3;1;10))>=DATEVALUE(MID(C1:C6;1;10)));0))
```

I have an excel file that has prices per productId combination ( columns A and B ) and by effective dates. 
As you can see it may contain duplicates for the productId combination and they are valid only after the date has passed. 
This is the formula i came up with till now but it only works if the rows are sorted by A B and C ( especially C should be sorted descending). 
In the example i am expecting the correct result price to be 600.00 but it returns 200.00 .

I understand why this happens. But i don't know how to fix it and make it work correctly. 
Correctly means :

Give the product ids:
D318JV  00B6

if effectiveDate >= 07/18/2019 00:00:00   =>  600.00

if effectiveDate between 07/07/2019 00:00:00  AND 07/18/2019    =>  400.00

if effectiveDate between 06/01/2019 00:00:00  AND 07/07/2019    =>  200.00

if effectiveDate before 06/01/2019 00:00:00  => N/A

Any help to make this formula work will be appreciated

Comment: I hope `E2=B2:B6` is a typo and should be `E2=B1:B6`, not some special requirement

Comment: Would you please clarify the following: In regards this comment: **“i am not looking for the max price, but the price that corresponds to the given date and productid . So given the product id we should somehow filter the results and from that we need to check which price has date equal or previous than the given date ( effective date).”** What should be the criteria used when two dates are given (i.e. effective Date between 07/07/2019 AND 07/18/2019 and there are prices for the following dates 07/07/2019; 08/07/2019; 17/07/2019 and 18/07/2019) in such cases which date\price should be used?

Answer (score 2):

Combining the approaches from the question and from comments to @matro's answer:

0. get the exact date (highest one meeting the criteria), using an array formula in cell E4 
   `=MAX(IF((E1=A1:A6)*(E2=B1:B6)*(E3>=C1:C6); C1:C6))` 
   (confirmed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
1. modify the original formula to 
   `=INDEX(D1:D6; MATCH(1; (E1=A1:A6)*(E2=B1:B6)*(E4=C1:C6); 0))`

Comment: Note for US and other regions: use `,` instead of `;` if that is the list separator in Operating system's locale settings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following ARRAY formula using **1 Formula only**:

```
=INDEX(D1:D6,MATCH(1,(E1=A1:A6)*(E2=B1:B6)*(C1:C6=MAX(IF(C1:C6<E3,C1:C6,0))),0))
```

Make sure you confirm the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. See screenshot of example working:

[image]

You may have to change the `,` for `;`. If that's the case the formula will look like:

```
=INDEX(D1:D6;MATCH(1;(E1=A1:A6)*(E2=B1:B6)*(C1:C6=MAX(IF(C1:C6<E3;C1:C6,0)));0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Kaiser has already provided the right answer, but if he can incorporate **DATEVALUE** into his function it will be even better. It seems that the original dates in column C (and possibly the look up date as well) are text.

So the final formula may look something like this:

```
{=INDEX(D1:D6,MATCH(1,(A1:A6=E1)*(B1:B6=E2)*(DATEVALUE(C1:C6)=MAX(IF(DATEVALUE(C1:C6)<DATEVALUE(E3),DATEVALUE(C1:C6),0))),0))}
```

Or like this in @isioutis' system:

```
{=INDEX(D1:D6;MATCH(1;(A1:A6=E1)*(B1:B6=E2)*(DATEVALUE(C1:C6)=MAX(IF(DATEVALUE(C1:C6)<DATEVALUE(E3);DATEVALUE(C1:C6);0)));0))}
```

My habit is to give name(s) to range(s) to make my formula easier to be interpreted, so if you do the following:

Name Column A as '**ProductId_A**'

Name Column B as '**ProductId_B**'

Name Column C as '**Date_List**'

Name Column D as '**Price_List**'

and name the look up criteria as

'**Lookup_A**'

'**Lookup_B**'

'**Lookup_Date**'

you will have a formula looks like this instead:

```
{=INDEX(Price_List,MATCH(1,(ProductId_A=Lookup_A)*(ProductId_B=Lookup_B)*(DATEVALUE(Date_List)=MAX(IF(DATEVALUE(Date_List)<DATEVALUE(Lookup_Date),DATEVALUE(Date_List),0))),0))}
```

or

```
{=INDEX(Price_List;MATCH(1;(ProductId_A=Lookup_A)*(ProductId_B=Lookup_B)*(DATEVALUE(Date_List)=MAX(IF(DATEVALUE(Date_List)<DATEVALUE(Lookup_Date);DATEVALUE(Date_List);0)));0))}
```

Please see below some test results (and note that the date format in my system is dd/mm/yyyy):

[image: Test Results]

One thing to note is that if the following statement by isioutis is valid,

> they are valid only after the date has passed

then the looked up price on **07/18/2019 00:00:00** should be **$400** as technically the day has not yet passed which means $600 is not the valid price for that date. Otherwise please use "**<=**" (less than and equal to) in the formula when comparing the look up date with the date list.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

**DATA:** Table with the following fields: Product, ID, Effective Date, Price

**Requirements:** Extract the Price of a Product Id that corresponds to a given date range.

**Assumptions:** This solution assumes that the Product, Id, Price and Date combinations are unique.

**Date Criteria:** The following table shows the several criteria formats that could be used to retrieve the Price of a Product Id based on an Effective Date, it also shows the selection to be applied for each criterion when the result of the criteria includes several items.

[image]

**Formulas:** As the table contains unique combinations of Product, Id, Price and Date, and the expected output is numeric (i.e. Price), the use of the `SUMIFS` function seems appropriate.

**Criteria:** *1.Equals*
**Formula:**

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID, 
[Effective Date range], #Date )
```

*Where:*
[Price range] = The Price column
[Product range] = The Product column
 #Product = The Product we need to find
[ID range] = The ID column
 #ID = The ID we need to find
[Effective Date range]  = The Effective Date column
 #Date = The Date we need to find

**Other Criteria:** The next five criteria might return several possible `Dates`, therefore we’ll use the function `AGGREGATE` to select the required `Date` as per the Criteria Table.
**Formula:**

```
= AGGREGATE( #Sel, 6, [Effective Date range] /
( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] #ƒ #Date) ), 1 )
```

*Where:*
 #Sel = The selection to be applied as per the Criteria Table *(i.e. 14 = Latest Date and 15 = Earliest Date)*
 #ƒ = The comparison to be applied base on the criteria required

Then we'll use the date resulting from the AGGREGATE function, in the SUMIFS function to obtain the required Price:
**Formula:**

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID,
[Effective Date range], #AGGREGATE )
```

*Where:*
 #AGGREGATE = The resulting date from the AGGREGATE function

For the last five criteria the *base formula* will be:

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID, [Effective Date range],
AGGREGATE( #Sel, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID)
* ( [Effective Date range] #ƒ #Date ) ), 1 ) )
```

and we just replace `#Sel` and `#ƒ` as follows:

**Criteria:** *2.Before*
 #Sel = 14
 #ƒ = `<`

**Criteria:** *3.Before or Equal*
 #Sel = 14
 #ƒ = `<=`

**Criteria:** *4.Between*
 #Sel   = 15
 #ƒ = `>=` and `<=`
 #Date1 = Date from
 #Date2 = Date to
**Formula:**

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID, [Effective Date range],
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID)
* ([Effective Date range] >= #Date1) * ([Effective Date range] <= #Date2) ), 1 ) )
```

**Criteria:** *5. After or Equal*
 #Sel   = 15
 #ƒ = `>=`

**Criteria:** *6.After*
 #Sel   = 15
 #ƒ = `>`

**Solution:** In order to apply the required formula for each criteria we need to combine all of them into one formula. Although that could be achieved with a series of nested `IF`s, instead we’ll use the function `CHOOSE`

**Formula:**

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID, [Effective Date range],
CHOOSE( #Criteria, #Date,
AGGREGATE( 14, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] < #Date) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 14, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] <= #Date) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] >= #Date1) * ([Effective Date range] <= #Date2) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] >= #Date) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, [Effective Date range] / ( ([Product range] = #Product) * ([ID range] = #ID) 
* ([Effective Date range] > #Date) ), 1 ) ) )
```

Where:
 #Criteria = Criteria applied as per the Criteria Table *(i.e. 1 to 6)*
 #ƒ = The comparison to be applied base on the criteria required

A formula array could be used to reduce further the length of the formula
**Formula Array:**

```
= SUMIFS( [Price range], [Product range], #Product, [ID range], #ID, [Effective Date range],
IF( #Criteria = 1, #Date,
AGGREGATE( LOOKUP( #Criteria, {1,"N/A";2,14;4,15} ), 6, [Effective Date range] /
( ( [Product range] = #Product ) * ( [ID range] = #ID )
* CHOOSE( #CRITERIA, "N/A",
[Effective Date range] < #Date, [Effective Date range] <= #Date,
([Effective Date range] >= #Date1) * ([Effective Date range] <= #Date2),
[Effective Date range] >= #Date,[Effective Date range] > #Date ) ), 1 ) ) )
```

**Implementation:**
Assuming the data table located at `B2:E8`

Enter this formula in cell `L6` and copy to `L7:L9`

```
= SUMIFS( $E$6:$E$11, $B$6:$B$11, $H$6, $C$6:$C$11, $H$7, $D$6:$D$11,
CHOOSE( LEFT( $I6 ), $J6,
AGGREGATE( 14, 6, $D$6:$D$11 / ( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 ) 
* ( $D$6:$D$11 < $J6 ) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 14, 6, $D$6:$D$11 / ( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 )
* ( $D$6:$D$11 <= $J6 ) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, $D$6:$D$11 / ( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 )
* ( $D$6:$D$11 >= $J6 ) * ( $D$6:$D$11 <= $K6 ) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, $D$6:$D$11 / ( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 )
* ( $D$6:$D$11 >= $J6 ) ), 1 ),
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, $D$6:$D$11 / ( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 )
* ( $D$6:$D$11 > $J6 ) ), 1 ) ) )
```

[image]

Enter this formula array in cell `M6` and copy to `M7:M9`

`FormulaArrays` *are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, the formula would be wrapped within `{` and `}` if entered correctly.*

```
= SUMIFS( $E$6:$E$11, $B$6:$B$11, $H$6, $C$6:$C$11, $H$7, $D$6:$D$11,
IF( --LEFT( $I6 ) = 1, $J6,
AGGREGATE( LOOKUP( --LEFT( $I6 ), {1,"N/A";2,14;4,15} ), 6, $D$6:$D$11 /
( ( $B$6:$B$11 = $H$6 ) * ( $C$6:$C$11 = $H$7 )
* CHOOSE( LEFT( $I6 ), "N/A",
$D$6:$D$11 < $J6, $D$6:$D$11 <= $J6,
( $D$6:$D$11 >= $J6 ) * ( $D$6:$D$11 <= $K6 ),
$D$6:$D$11 >= $J6, $D$6:$D$11 > $J6 ) ), 1 ) ) )
```

[image]

*An alternate format is seen in the figure below:*

[image]

Suggested reading about the resources used:
[AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df), 
[CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc), 
[SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to find relevant price (= output variable) for a given product at a given time (= input variables).

I tried to reconstruct your use case using only a simple productID (1 and 2) together with effective date and price as stated in your question. I think I found the solution and used [this site](https://exceljet.net/formula/maximum-if-multiple-criteria) to get to it.

In general, the solution might be array formula with combination of `MAX` and `IF` function. A little bit of analysis of your requirement was also needed as follows:

1. **We want to find exact productID** - first condition in if statement
2. **We want to find the latest (or max) price applied at a given date** - second condition in if statement (the effective date has to be less or equal to the given date) together with `MAX` function applied on the price column.

Please let me know, if my explanation together with the source page is not clear enough.

If that would be the case, [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmFDu3uJL0lK10eMlWXHCI5iY37u) is my sample Excel file with proposed solution.

Thanks and regards.

Matej

Comment: `{=MAX(IF((B4:B9=F4) * (C4:C9<=G4),D4:D9))}` will give the highest price from rows that meet the conditions (and NOT the price for maximum date as seems to be required)

Comment: Hello @Aprillion. I am not sure how this applies to the business requirement, could you please explain on the example that isioutis posted at the end of his question? Thanks and regards.

Comment: @Aprillion i am not looking for the max price , but the price that corresponds to the given date and productid . So given the product id we should somehow filter the results and from that we need to check which price has date equal or previous than the given date ( effective date) . 
But if we apply this to the formula you suggested i think it gets the correct date so all we need is the price 
`{=MAX(IF((B4:B9=F4) * (C4:C9<=G4),C4:C9))}`

Comment: I didn't suggest the formula, I commented that the formula used by @matro will provide max price, which is incorrect. sorry for the cofusion

Comment: Sorry i wanted to mention @matro on this

Comment: Hi @isioutis, I am not sure if I understand your comment, the MAX function was only the way how did I manage to obtain relevant price for productID and time provided. 
In other words, does the PoC provide required output if you change the input date, please? From my point of view, it yield the correct price based on inputs unless I am missing something in your requirement.